# Custom AvroSchemaMessageConverter not registered

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a `@SpringBootApplication` class with the following bean defined:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public MessageConverter avroSchemaMessageConverter() {
  return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("avro/bytes"));
}
```

When I run a `@SpringBootTest` and debug it, I've noticed that this bean isn't created before I breakpoint on the constructor for `CompositeMessageConverterFactory`. As a list of custom converters is passed as an argument to this class, my custom AvroSchemaMessageConverter is never registered.

This condition results in the following error when I try to send the Avro message to my `@Output` channel later in my test:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert message: 'GenericMessage [payload={omitted for privacy reasons}, headers={id=omitted, contentType=avro/bytes, __TypeId__=com.example.ExampleRecord, timestamp=1576877638777}]' to outbound message.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$OutboundContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.doPreSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$AbstractContentTypeInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:608)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:443)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

How do I ensure that my bean is added to Spring's Application Context before the `CompositeMessageConverterFactory` is initialized with its list of converters?

Comment: what version of spring-cloud-stream you're using?

Comment: Greenwich.SR4. I'm trying to work around an issue we've run across. Our app uses ```@EnableSchemaRegistryClient```, and when we run a ```@SpringBootTest``` integration test and write our message to an ```@Output``` channel, we end up failing because the DefaultSchemaRegistryClient tries to register a schema by posting to http://localhost:8990. I'm struggling trying to figure out the best approach to get this working.

Comment: We're able to send messages in our tests to ```@Input``` channels, but once we try to send a message to the ```@Output``` channel, the test fails. I think it's failing due to what is described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/schema-evolution.html#_avro_schema_registry_client_message_converters.

Comment: And, of course, there isn't anything running on http://localhost:8990 when we run our Maven builds. How might we best solve for this dilemma? Is there a way to mock or stub in a AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter that doesn't delegate to the DefaultSchemaRegistryClient to register the schema while we're running our JUnit tests?

Comment: Add `@StreamMessageConverter` annotation on your converter.

Comment: Oleg, your suggestion is just what I needed to get my tests working. Can you leave this as an answer?

Comment: I have upgraded my ```spring-cloud-stream``` dependency to ```3.0.1-RELEASE```, and now I see that ```@StreamMessageConverter``` is now deprecated. According to the Javadoc, it was required so that the bean would be added to the ```org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.CompositeMessageConverterFactory```. Now that this class is deprecated and no longer used by the framework, how will my bean be added to the ```CompositeMessageConverterFactory```? This was the problem I had prior to upgrading, and I want to ensure my solution will still work after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding @StreamMessageConverter as Oleg Zhurakousky suggested solved this issue for me.

Comment: Note that since spring-cloud-stream version 3.x  (Horhsam) it is not necessary.